# How can I share webpack.config snippets between projects?

Tags: npm, webpack-2

I have several webpack configurations with very similar webpack.config files. I like to put webpack.config parts in a shared module that (I include the shared module with "npm link"), but that doesn't work as can't find dependencies, like "webpack" as it's the first dependency it encounters.

```
17 07 2017 14:49:32.694:ERROR [config]: Invalid config file!
  Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
```

First webpack.config lines:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
....
```

How can I instruct webpack to search for the included dependences in node_modules of the project that includes the webpack.config?

I tried to realise this by adding the following to the resolve webpack.config section, but that doesn't help:

> modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"), "node_modules"]

I think it's not used by the webpack.config itself but by the JS code that is processed by webpack.config.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this , I have the same requirement and I have been looking around and almost nothing

Comment: Yes, exactly I did 2 weeks ago, forgot to answer it here, I will now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by passing in required root dir as argument to the common webpack config, and use that to change the __dirname variable that is used to find plugins and other stuff.

In code: 
The webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const loader = require('lodash/fp');
const common = require('bdh-common-js/etc/webpack/webpack.config.common');

module.exports = function (env) {
    if (env === undefined) {
        env = {};
    }
    env.rootdir = __dirname; // Add the root dir that can be used by the included webpack config.

    const result = loader.compose(
        function () {
            return common(env)
        }
        // Any other "fragments" go here.
    )();

    // Customize the webpack config:
    result.entry = {
        entry: ['./src/entry.js', './src/js/utils.js'],
    }
    result.resolve.alias.Context = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/context');
    ...... more stuff..
    return result;
}
```

And the common webpack.config part that receives the argument:

```
module.exports = function (env) { 
    if (env !== undefined) {
        if (env.rootdir !== undefined) {
            __dirname = env.rootdir;
        }
    }
  ....
    const node_modules = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');
    const webpack = require(node_modules + '/webpack');
    const CleanWebpackPlugin = require(node_modules + '/clean-webpack-plugin');
 ....

}
```

Comment: Overriding `__dirname` indeed helped. Thanks!