# Wepback and front end monorepo

Tags: webpack, frontend, monorepo

Researching a way to use Webpack with front end monorepo. I was wondering if I can use one common Webpack config and place it to the root directory and then extend this config in other apps. But, when I tried to setup common configuration and extend it I was stuck into running context, so the building is running in the root directory, not in each of apps.

My question is: does webpack have Monorepo support or can I use common configs and then override what I need in each of the applications, but the main configuration is stored in the root?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144918/how-can-i-share-webpack-config-snippets-between-projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main complexity was in reusing webpack configuration for different apps. I resolved that by moving the common functionality to separate package (npm package). It contains common, dev, and prod configs. Each of apps has own configuration for each of environments. Using `merge` functionality I can re-use existing configuration and override with specific configuration that required by specific application.